# How to handle Thread was being aborted message on c#?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have a simple **win-form** with two buttons on it , one button to start and another one to stop my thread.

But, when I press stop button then I encounter with this error : "Thread was being aborted."

What is the wrong with my codes?

```
    Thread th_ModeSendingWorks;
    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        th_ModeSendingWorks = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Works));
        th_ModeSendingWorks.Start();
    }

    private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        th_ModeSendingWorks.Abort();
        textBox1.AppendText("------------------");
    }

    private void Works()
    {
        try
        {
            while (th_ModeSendingWorks.IsAlive)
            {
                textBox1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    textBox1.AppendText("xxxxxxxxxxx");
                    textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
                });

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            textBox1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
            {
                textBox1.AppendText("err:" + err.Message);
                textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: you'll get a lot of people talking about how aborting threads is bad, but nothing is wrong with getting a 'thread is being aborted' message. Just wrap the necessary code in `try {} catch {}` and ignore that error.

Comment: you mean ,it's normal?

Comment: Yes - truthfully there is no clean way to abort a thread. That's why cancellation tokens are the future.

Comment: what is the alternative way?

Comment: Well you can write your thread to check for a "cancellation token" like variable and abort itself when a flag is raised. Before your thread does anything, it can check to see if a boolean cancel = true or something like that. If so, it can return. Then, your form can set it to true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it's normal?

Yes...as user1274820 mentioned, see [Thread.Abort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When this method is invoked on a thread, the system throws a
>   ThreadAbortException in the thread to abort it.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not use Thread.Abort.** This method is reserved for when the .NET runtime needs to forcibly kill threads in order to unload your program.

You can only "safely" use this if you're about to unload an AppDomain and want to get rid of threads running in it first.

To get rid of a thread, write it in cooperative mode. This means that the thread should periodically check some kind of flag, and if the flag is set, exit normally out of the thread method. To "kill" the thread, simply set the flag and wait for the thread to exit.